# How do I let the user set the output directory for files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I am writing a very basic batch script to run an MD5 hash. I need it to ask the user for an output directory, then ask for an IP address output, then map a drive letter to this output. I can get it to ask, but it doesn't output the file to the chosen directory. It puts it in the local directory the script was run from. It also won't map a drive letter to it.Can anyone help me fix this? The MD5 hash should be sent to the user chosen directory.

```
@ECHO OFF
pause
REM This section prompts user for output location 

:start
CLS
set /p direct="Enter the directory output location: "

dir %1 %direct% > investigation.txt 
pause

REM 

set /p direct="Enter the IP output location: "

dir %1 > investigation.txt 
pause

REM Map share 
@echo Map Share
@echo off 
net use z: \\%1
pause

REM This section appends the date and time of the investigation. 
@Echo Date and Time 
@Echo off
date /T >> investigation.txt && time /T >> INVESTIGATION.TXT 
pause 

REM This step creates the MD5 hash 


@echo MD5 VALUE
@echo off 
MD5DEEP investigation.txt > Hash.txt


pause 

REM This step creates the SHA1 hash
echo SHA1 VALUE
@echo off 
SHA1DEEP investigation.txt >> Hash.txt  
pause
```

Comment: Crossposted to [so]. Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: As I already told you on [so] you seem to be confused what `%1` is used for. It is a parameter passed to the batch file when you call it.

Comment: Why have you got bash and linux tags?

Comment: Telling me I don't know what I am doing isn't helpful. I already know this. I need a solution to make the script work. Are people always this unhelpful here?

Comment: I don't have a solution because your question is unclear about what you are trying to do. There are many things wrong with your batch file. You need to find some good training material.

Comment: As I explained above:

a. Prompt the user for an output location (IP address and shared folder name) and then map a drive letter to that location.  
b. The batch file should write a file with the output of all the commands run to the location specified in step ‘a’ above. 
c. The batch file should also write to the file the time and date when the batch file was started and completed.
d. The batch file should also write a separate file to the location in step ‘a’ with the md5 and sha1 hashes for the command output file created above.

Answer (score 0):

## Some explanations

### How it Works

```
set /p Folder=Enter folder's path: 

set /p IP=Enter computer's IP:
```

Once you have them set with `%Folder%` and `%IP%` values, you can map the remote path to a letter

```
net use x: "\\%IP%\%Folder%"
```

Here it maps to the letter `x` creating a virtual `X` drive, always double quote because the folder may contain <s>special characters</s> spaces.

---

### Main Issue

```
dir %1 > investigation.txt
```

Plain `investigation.txt` without the path specified like `c:\SomeFolder\investigation.txt` would create the file in the current directory, that is within the folder the script ran from.

So, you should specify the directory as well, and not just file's name in order to save the output to a file in the directory you want it to be saved in.

Moreover, `%1` is first argument, that is the value of the first parameter passed to file, parameter is what you type after its name, that is after calling the file, eg `mybatchfile.bat parameter1 parameter2`'s values would be `%1` and `%2` respectively inside the batch file.

So I think, the script is wrong, and you should learn to understand what the contents do, and correct some parts of it.

---

### Notes

- IP should be in `192.168.1.1` format, that's four numbers, three dots, in order it to work
- You can use hostname, that is the name of the computer, instead of its address, that's IP
- To learn your computer's name: `echo %ComputerName%`